# How efficient is GHCs garbage collector (on mobile devices)?

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection

So this has to have come up several thousand times before, but I just read [this article](http://sealedabstract.com/rants/why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow/) that goes into great detail why garbage collection on Android and iOS is terrible slow.

One of the main points is that garbage collection is fine as long as there is plenty of free space for the collectors to work in.

My question is: is the memory managment implementation of GHC also susceptible to this?

Comment: GHC's garbage collector can do some optimisations that wouldn't be possible in a non–purely-functional language (I remember some stuff about pointers that can't refer "into the future" (i.e. to objects created after the containing object), because everything is immutable). But of course every non-deterministic garbage collector is susceptible to memory shortage issues to some degree; I don't expect GHC to fare much better than JVMs in this regard.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The part about pointers that can't refer "into the future" seems fishy. Haskell is lazy, it's not only possible but trivial to create arbitrarily large cycles, and depending on the program parts of these cycles may be created and live to be promoted to the oldest generation before the thunk representing the rest of the cycle is evaluated. Put differently, everything *is* mutable - thunks are mutated when evaluated (replaced with the result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be, although the full situation is more complicated.  GHC primarily uses a copying collector.  GC's are triggered when the heap grows by some amount, [currently 2x](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/GC).  Since the strategy of a copying collector is to copy live objects into new memory, it's very important that you have free RAM available, although not 6x your live data size as that article indicates.  IIRC for GHC about 2.5-3x is about the minimum.

GHC also provides a compacting collector, which does not require nearly so much extra RAM.  The choice between compacting and copying collection schemes is made dynamically depending on memory usage and the [RTS's `-c` and `-M` flags](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html).

Comment: My thought was that most of the values in Haskell have a very defined lifetime. I guess that the compiler should know when to delete a value , in most cases right after the value goes out of scope. As long as it is a pure function it should be possible to determine the lifetime of almost every value?

Comment: @Florian: it's a little more complicated than that, due to laziness/closures.  Even if a value goes out of scope, it might be captured in a closure or thunk and need to be retained until that is evaluated.  I think it could be a viable approach, but it's not what GHC does.  Perhaps JHC/UHC manage memory differently, but I don't know much about those implementations.